# How can I generate the Average time difference from a set of results in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to calculate the average of the difference between two dates for the returned results.  I have already managed to return the timestamp number to a number of days, and this works perfectly fine, but I now need to calculate the average difference in days for those returned results.  This is my code:

```
select 
    SUPPORTCALL.CALL_ID "Call ID",
    PROBLEMTYPE.PROBLEMCATEGORY "Problem Category",
    SUPPORTCALL.CALLDATETIME "Opened Date/Time",
    SUPPORTCALL.RESOLVEDDATETIME "Resolved Date/Time",
    TRUNC(SUPPORTCALL.RESOLVEDDATETIME) - TRUNC(SUPPORTCALL.CALLDATETIME) DTR
    
from
    SUPPORTCALL,
    PROBLEMTYPE
where
    SUPPORTCALL.PROBLEM_ID=PROBLEMTYPE.PROBLEM_ID and
    PROBLEMTYPE.PROBLEMCATEGORY='VMware' and
    RESOLVEDDATETIME is not null
```

The above returns the following result:

```
Call ID Problem Category                                   Opened Date/Time             Resolved Date/Time                  DTR
    19 VMware                                             05-MAR-18 15.14.23.100000000 06-APR-18 11.14.23.100000000         32
    18 VMware                                             01-APR-18 11.14.23.100000000 02-APR-18 11.14.23.100000000          1
     8 VMware                                             23-MAR-18 15.14.23.100000000 25-MAR-18 11.14.23.100000000          2
     7 VMware                                             21-MAR-18 11.14.23.100000000 22-MAR-18 11.14.23.100000000          1
```

[Output from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IzX8.png)

I am a bit lost on getting the average number of the returned results.

TIA
Simon

Comment: You want to return a single row with the one value 9 (i.e. (32+1+2+1)/4)? Then just `select avg(dtr) from ( <your query here> );`.

Comment: You are using a deprecated join syntax by the way. And by "deprecated" I mean a join syntax that got out of fashion in the **1990s**! Use explicit joins instead `FROM supportcall sc INNER JOIN problemtype pt ON pt.problem_id = sc.problem_id and pt.problemcategory = 'VMware'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract two timestamps to get an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type and then use `EXTRACT` to get the component parts of the interval to give the time difference. Then to get the average you can use the `AVG` function. If you want to get all the other data as well then you can use `AVG` as an analytic function:

```sql
select s.CALL_ID "Call ID",
       p.PROBLEMCATEGORY "Problem Category",
       s.CALLDATETIME "Opened Date/Time",
       s.RESOLVEDDATETIME "Resolved Date/Time",
       EXTRACT(DAY FROM s.RESOLVEDDATETIME - s.CALLDATETIME)
       + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM s.RESOLVEDDATETIME - s.CALLDATETIME)/24
       + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM s.RESOLVEDDATETIME - s.CALLDATETIME)/24/60
       + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM s.RESOLVEDDATETIME - s.CALLDATETIME)/24/60/60 AS diff,
       AVG(
         EXTRACT(DAY FROM s.RESOLVEDDATETIME - s.CALLDATETIME)
         + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM s.RESOLVEDDATETIME - s.CALLDATETIME)/24
         + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM s.RESOLVEDDATETIME - s.CALLDATETIME)/24/60
         + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM s.RESOLVEDDATETIME - s.CALLDATETIME)/24/60/60  
       ) OVER () AS avg_diff
from   SUPPORTCALL s
       INNER JOIN PROBLEMTYPE p
       ON (s.PROBLEM_ID = p.PROBLEM_ID)
where  p.PROBLEMCATEGORY='VMware'
and    RESOLVEDDATETIME is not null
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE supportcall (Call_ID, Problem_ID, calldatetime, resolveddatetime ) AS
  SELECT 19, 1, TIMESTAMP '2018-03-05 15:14:23.1', TIMESTAMP '2018-04-06 11:14:23.1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 18, 1, TIMESTAMP '2018-04-01 11:14:23.1', TIMESTAMP '2018-04-02 11:14:23.1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  8, 1, TIMESTAMP '2018-03-23 15:14:23.1', TIMESTAMP '2018-03-25 11:14:23.1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  7, 1, TIMESTAMP '2018-03-21 11:14:23.1', TIMESTAMP '2018-03-22 11:14:23.1' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE problemtype (problem_id, ProblemCategory) AS
SELECT 1, 'VMware' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| Call ID | Problem Category | Opened Date/Time | Resolved Date/Time | DIFF | AVG_DIFF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | VMware | 05-MAR-18 15.14.23.100000000 | 06-APR-18 11.14.23.100000000 | 31.83333333333333333333333333333333333333 | 8.91666666666666666666666666666666666667 |
| 18 | VMware | 01-APR-18 11.14.23.100000000 | 02-APR-18 11.14.23.100000000 | 1 | 8.91666666666666666666666666666666666667 |
| 8 | VMware | 23-MAR-18 15.14.23.100000000 | 25-MAR-18 11.14.23.100000000 | 1.83333333333333333333333333333333333333 | 8.91666666666666666666666666666666666667 |
| 7 | VMware | 21-MAR-18 11.14.23.100000000 | 22-MAR-18 11.14.23.100000000 | 1 | 8.91666666666666666666666666666666666667 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZAyNgfw9)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the comments / replies

After much thought and further research I decided that the assignment question is so ambiguous whether you are to return a specific problem category or show all problem categories and their averages.  So I decided to show all categories that have resolved cases and their Average "Days to Resolve" by using GROUP BY, my code ended up like this:

```
SELECT
    AVG(TRUNC(SUPPORTCALL.RESOLVEDDATETIME) - TRUNC(SUPPORTCALL.CALLDATETIME)) "Avg DTR",
    PROBLEMTYPE.PROBLEMCATEGORY "Problem Category"
FROM
    SUPPORTCALL,
    PROBLEMTYPE
WHERE
    SUPPORTCALL.PROBLEM_ID=PROBLEMTYPE.PROBLEM_ID AND
    SUPPORTCALL.RESOLVEDDATETIME IS NOT NULL
    
GROUP BY PROBLEMTYPE.PROBLEMCATEGORY
```

Which Resulted in the following output:

```
    Avg DTR Problem Category                                  
         31 Servers                                           
          3 Office                                            
          9 VMware
```